# Ive made a slider that adjust the games volume in the main menu but the music reverts to normal when the scene is changed to the actual game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can i make it so changes i made in the main menu scene are carried over into the game scene?

below is the code i used for the music player.

```
// Reference to Audio Source component
private AudioSource audioSrc;

// Music volume variable that will be modified
// by dragging slider knob
private float musicVolume = 1f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    // Assign Audio Source component to control it
    audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    // Setting volume option of Audio Source to be equal to musicVolume
    audioSrc.volume = musicVolume;
}

// Method that is called by slider game object
// This method takes vol value passed by slider
// and sets it as musicValue
public void SetVolume(float vol)
{
    musicVolume = vol;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a new instance of this script on every scene?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options

1. Make the `musicVolume` a `static` so the value is "shared" between all instances of that class.

   ```
   private static float musicVolume = 1.0f;
   ```
2. Or use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) to use allways the same component in all Scenes.

   ```
   private void Awake ()
   {
       DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
   }
   ```

   but than make sure you have that object with this component only included once in the first Scene so you don't have multiple objects later.
3. you could use a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) for this kind of settings. This is more powerful and flexible and "orthodox" than using a `static` value.

   It is a bit more complicated to get into this but it is worth it. Here is a [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects).

   ```
   [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New SettingsAsset", menuName = "Example/SettingsAsset"]
   public class SettingsAsset : ScriptableObject 
   {
        public float musicVolume = 1.0f;
   }
   ```

   create one SetttingsAsset by right click in the `ProjectView` (Assets) and in the menu find `Example` -> `SettingsAsset`

   and than reference these settings in all Scenes and components wherever needed. In this case e.g.

   ```
   // Reference in the inspector
   public SettingsAsset settings;

   // ...

   // Though I doubt you would need to do this in Update 
   // If you only change the settings from within a separate settings scene
   // you probably should do this only once
   private void Update()
   {
       audioSrc.volume = settings.musicVolume;
   }
   ```